# Circle Around the Unpatterned Buttons in size CSS

Tags: html, css

I made a circle around the icon with CSS, this to be the button, but each button was different, even if I set a size. How can I make it standardized?
The icons are from font awesome.

The css part is just the css of the buttons, I add just this part to be more clear, cause de css is too long.

```css
.controls {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.controls button {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.controls #stop {
  display: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.controls #reset {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*BELOW PART OF THE ICON CIRCLE*/

.controls i {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #48bf91;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya+Sans:wght@400;700&family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b41e2a9200.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icons8-whole-apple-16.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title id="titulo">Pomodoro Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Pomodoro Timer</h1>
            <div class="painel">
                <span id="work">Work</span>
                <span id="break">Break</span>
            </div>
            <div class="timer">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="time">
                       <span id="minutes"></span>
                       <span>:</span>
                       <span id="seconds"></span> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <button id="start" onclick="start()"><i class="fa-solid fa-play"></i></button>
                <a id="stop" href="#" onclick="stop()"><i class="fa-solid fa-stop"></i></a>
                <a id="reset" href="#" onclick="reset()"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-rotate-left"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="social">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/carlos.curcino/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="https://github.com/carloscurcino"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/carlos-daniel-curcino-mendes-7150141b5/"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </section>
    <section class="content">
        <article>
            <div id="text1">
               <h1>O que é pomodoro?</h1>
                <p>A técnica de pomodoro é uma forma de gerenciamento de tempo, de forma a utilizar melhor o seu tempo e se concentrar melhor no que está fazendo de forma que não se sobrecarregue mentalmente. O sistema incentiva a pessoa a focar de maneira intensa e integral em apenas uma tarefa ao longo de exatos 25 minutos. A técnica foi desenvolvida por Francesco Cirillo no final dos anos 1980. A técnica recebeu esse nome pois Francesco utilizava um cronômetro em forma de tomate, que é Pomodoro em italiano. </p> 
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Como funciona?</h2>
                <p>O sistema pomodoro consiste em 25 minutos de concentração em uma tarefa, seguida de 5 minutos de descanso. Os ciclos de 25 minutos são chamados de Pomodoros, e para organizar melhor a realização da sua tarefa é bom calcular quantos pomodoros serão necessários para a tarefa. Também é aconselhável que a cada 4 ciclos, fazer uma pausa mais longa de 15 a 30 minutos. Esses intervalos entres os pomodoros são fundamentais para “oxigenar o seu cérebro” e aumentar a agilidade mental. </p>  
            </div>
            
        </article>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>Desenvolvido por &copy;CarlosCurcino</p>
       
    </footer>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Play button was also not centered for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i9Gg.png)

[Note: when you click on play, the two buttons appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7sDU.png)

Comment: Your HTML might help understanding and seeing your issue. I turned your code into a snippet you can edit again ;)

Comment: I added the html, if you can help me I would appreciate it : )

Answer (score 0):

To make it standardized use one css class to add the styles. so that the same styles will be applied to all elements that uses it.
Hope that this is what you are expecting.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAF0v.png

style.css

```
/*BELOW PART OF THE ICON CIRCLE*/
  .controls{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .controls button {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .controls i {
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #48bf91;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="controls">
         <button><i class="fas fa-play"></i> </button>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">
         <button><i class="fas fa-stop"></i> </button>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">
         <button><i class="fas fa-undo"></i> </button>
    </div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

To center the play button I used the `justify-content: center;` `align-items: center;` in the div element that button is contained.